# Asp.net related to Sql Database and Link Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve 100 questions from sql database in Discover.aspx page.
But retrieved questions should be in LinkButton not in text format.

Dont know how many LinkButton to use as questions may increase.

Try to understand my question. :)

Java developers also answer because i am facing this problem in making a forum website using java and Asp.net.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. The question is too broad.

Comment: Actually I am making a project using Asp.net. Topic is Code Portal. I made login page, register page, question posting by user page. Now i am at the end of the project I just have to show all the questions asked by the user in different LinkButtons so when any user will click on a particular question then answers saved in Sql Db will appear,

Comment: Again: Show what you have tried so far. And remove the Java tag to focus on your actual problem. You receive nothing but downvotes otherwise.

Comment: After getting this problem i cant even try. I cant use for_loop as ID of every control is different.  I dont want any code help. I just need logical help. thats it.  I removed that tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asp:listview control would do what you want quite easily. In the itemtemplate of the listview you can insert your linkbutton control. In codebehind you can do

```
listview1.datasource = sqlresults;
listview1.databind();
```

Then whatever is in the item template would be repeated for each record in the data source. Within the item template, you can also use syntax to insert data dynamically from the data source: <%#Eval("field name")%>.

Handling the click event is slightly different than usual. You would need to handle the listview item command event and use the sender to determine which button was clicked.

Theres plenty of online documentation which will help you figure out how achieve all of this with the listview control.

Comment: gridviewcontrol can also do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use listView then you can try this.

I am providing you logical explanation. In a for loop, create objects for LinkButton class. Assign Name to each object with the variable used in for loop, For Ex:

```
for(int i=1;i<=Count(Rows);i++)
{
LinkButton lb=new LinkButton();
lb.Name="lb"+i.ToString();
lb.Text = Your Question Data Here;
Add lb to a Grid or in a panel so that it is visible on the page.
}
```

Comment: this code not working in asp.net

Comment: it will work in java, i think

Comment: Dude dont tell me tat u simply copied this code and started complaining that it dosent work

Comment: no, i have that much brain. :P

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse   u dont need to make object of any control in asp.net unlike in java.

Comment: This is C#, a strong language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative, functional, procedural, generic, **object-oriented (class-based)**, and component-oriented programming disciplines.

Object are made with C#, ASP.NET is just the frontend.

Comment: i know, my problem is solved. But whenever i go to backend then i never see any object creation of any control that i drag and drop. I think IDE do it internally.

Comment: Have you ever looked at the designer file. In the solution explorer expand the aspx page you will see two other pages one is the aspx.cs and the other is the aspx.cx designer page. Visual studio automatically generates this file so that all the objects are created